# Accessing Intune graph api using send-on-behalf authorization gives response as unauthorized

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I Followed the [Active Directory .NET WebAPI onBehalfOf](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) sample.

In the web api created another endpoint to access Intune app protection policy from url
    `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/managedAppPolicies`, 
in azure provided permission to app to access Graph API.

In the call to `AquireTokenAsync` changed the resource Id to `https://graph.microsoft.com/`.

This returned the JWT token that contained:

```json
"aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
"scp": "DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All User.Read",
```

However fetching the endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/managedAppPolicies
```

Returns an HTTP response of `401 Unauthorized`.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

This generally implies one or both of the following issues:

- You need to obtain [Admin Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#admin-consent). The `DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All` scope requires that an Admin consent to the permissions before a normal user can can authorize the scope.
- You're app's registration doesn't have the correct scopes defined in Azure. Make sure your registration is selection scopes for Microsoft Graph and not Azure AD Graph API. These are two distinct APIs and the differences are greater than simply the resource URI.

Also note that the Client Credentials grant (aka Application scope) isn't supported by the Intune APIs. You can only call these endpoints using Delegated permissions (Authorization Code or Implicit grants).

Comment: I got the consent dialog with both permissions (DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All User.Read) listed.  Also in the azure app I have  given permission to Microsoft graph api. No luck still I get the same error.

Comment: Does your account have permission to execute these activities from Intune? In other words, is this account either a "Global Administrator" or "Intune Service Administrator"?

Comment: Yes it does,  I have tried through Postman the Authorization code grant flow and I am able to access the Intune graph endpoints.

Comment: Doh! I just realized that demo was using Client Credentials (aka Application permissions). App scopes are [not supported by Intune](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/9355eca5ec9358388f939e00234078c5aab60d2a/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_deviceappmanagement_list_managedapppolicy.md).